# Spinner in ListView preventing highlighting in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

I'm trying to place a spinner inside a list view item in android.  The problem is this seems to prevent the row from being highlighted during a press and the onItemClickListener is not getting called by the ListView.  Basically I am trying to mimic the functionality in the Google Music app.  Does anyone know how to do this?  This is the code I have been trying  (I know it may not be the best... just throwing together a quick sample which shows the problem):

Activity:

```
public class ListViewTestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        DataHolder data = new DataHolder(this);
        DataHolder data1 = new DataHolder(this);
        DataHolder data2 = new DataHolder(this);
        DataHolder data3 = new DataHolder(this);
        DataHolder data4 = new DataHolder(this);

        DataAdapter d = new DataAdapter(this, R.layout.rowview, new DataHolder[] { data, data1, data2, data3, data4 });
        listView.setAdapter(d);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "look at me!");

            }
        });
    }
}


public class DataHolder {

    private int selected;
    private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

    public DataHolder(Context parent) {
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(parent, R.array.choices, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }

    public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> getAdapter() {
        return adapter;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return (String) adapter.getItem(selected);
    }

    public int getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(int selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

}
```

This is the list adapter:

```
public class DataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataHolder> {

    private Activity myContext;

    public DataAdapter(Activity context, int textViewResourceId, DataHolder[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        myContext = context;
    }

    // We keep this ViewHolder object to save time. It's quicker than findViewById() when repainting.
    static class ViewHolder {
        protected DataHolder data;
        protected TextView text;
        protected Spinner spin;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;

        // Check to see if this row has already been painted once.
        if (convertView == null) {

            // If it hasn't, set up everything:
            LayoutInflater inflator = myContext.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowview, null);

            // Make a new ViewHolder for this row, and modify its data and spinner:
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            viewHolder.data = new DataHolder(myContext);
            viewHolder.spin = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spin);
            viewHolder.spin.setAdapter(viewHolder.data.getAdapter());

            // Used to handle events when the user changes the Spinner selection:
            viewHolder.spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    viewHolder.data.setSelected(arg2);
                    viewHolder.text.setText(viewHolder.data.getText());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    Log.d("DBGINF", "asdf");
                }

            });

            // Update the TextView to reflect what's in the Spinner
            viewHolder.text.setText(viewHolder.data.getText());

            view.setTag(viewHolder);

            Log.d("DBGINF", viewHolder.text.getText() + "");
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        // This is what gets called every time the ListView refreshes
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(getItem(position).getText());
        holder.spin.setSelection(getItem(position).getSelected());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Main layout for activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout for a row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="1" >
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" android:textSize="25sp" />
    <Spinner android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spin" android:prompt="@string/choice_prompt"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with ImageButton, and what was needed was to do

```
mImageButton.setFocusable(false);
```

I can't garantee it's the same for Spinner, but my money is on it.

Best regards.

Comment: That seemed to get the highlight and callback working correctly.  Now my problem is that the Spinner area is now a darker blue when the row is tapped.  Anyway to fix that?  Sorry still quite new to Android development.

Comment: Once more I believe ImageButton could come to your aid, especially the very first things on [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) page. No garantees whatsoever.

Comment: I was playing with the selectors before.  Was hoping there was a more elegant/easier way.  I ended up just having two selectors and switching them out when depending on if the user was tapping on the spinner or other parts of the list item.